# No me funciona $scope de AngularJS (Angular 1) para una variable

Tags: angularjs, json

Sucede que estoy haciendo una consulta mediante `get` de AngularJS, llamando datos en formato `JSON`. Como pueden observar, en el metodo `get` utilizo la variable `$scope.datos`, de la cual, obtengo resultado correcto.

```
app.controller('programador', function($scope,$http) {


      // La funcion get() que hace la solicitud para obtener los datos
        $scope.get = function(id){
          // Si la Id esta en blanco, entonces la solicitud es general
          if(id=="") {
            $http.get("api/sala").then(function (response) {
                $scope.datos = response.data.data;
                //Materialize.toast(response.data.statusMessage, 4000);

            }, function(response) {
              // Aqui va el codigo en caso de error
            });
        // Si la Id no esta en blanco, la solicitud se hace a un elemento especifico
          } else {
            $http.get("api/sala/" + id).then(function (response) {
                $scope.datos = response.data.data[0];
                //Materialize.toast(response.data.statusMessage, 4000);
            }, function(response) {
              // Aqui va el codigo en caso de error
            });
          }
        }

        setInterval(function() {
          $scope.get('');
        }, 2000);

        angular.element(document).ready(function () {


          $scope.config = {
            schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
            now: new Date(),
            editable: true, // enable draggable events
            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
            aspectRatio: 1.8,
            scrollTime: '00:00', // undo default 6am scrollTime
            header: {
              left: 'today prev,next',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'timelineDay,timelineThreeDays,agendaWeek,month'


            },
            defaultView: 'timelineDay',
            views: {
              // timelineThreeDays: {
              //  type: 'timeline',
              //  duration: { days: 3 }
              // }
            },
            resourceLabelText: 'Salas disponibles',
            resources : $scope.datos,
            events: [
              { id: '1', resourceId: '1', start: '2017-02-07T02:00:00', end: '2017-02-07T07:00:00', title: 'event 1' },
              { id: '2', resourceId: '2', start: '2017-02-07T05:00:00', end: '2017-02-07T22:00:00', title: 'event 2' },
              { id: '3', resourceId: '3', start: '2017-02-06', end: '2017-02-08', title: 'event 3' },
              { id: '4', resourceId: '4', start: '2017-02-07T03:00:00', end: '2017-02-07T08:00:00', title: 'event 4' },
              { id: '5', resourceId: '5', start: '2017-02-07T00:30:00', end: '2017-02-07T02:30:00', title: 'event 5' }
            ],
            drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) {
              console.log('drop', date.format(), resourceId);

              // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
              if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                $(this).remove();
              }
            },
            eventReceive: function(event) { // called when a proper external event is dropped
              console.log('eventReceive', event);
            },
            eventDrop: function(event) { // called when an event (already on the calendar) is moved
              console.log('eventDrop', event);
            }
          };


          $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {
            // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
            $(this).data('event', {
              title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
              stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
            });
            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable({
              zIndex: 999,
              revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
              revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
            });
          });

          /* initialize the calendar
          -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar($scope.config);


        });
```

Este es la respuesta

> {"schedulerLicenseKey":"CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives","now":"2017-02-20T03:37:16.701Z","editable":true,"droppable":true,"aspectRatio":1.8,"scrollTime":"00:00","header":{"left":"today prev,next","center":"title","right":"timelineDay,timelineThreeDays,agendaWeek,month"},"defaultView":"timelineDay","views":{},"resourceLabelText":"Salas disponibles","resources":[],"events":[{"id":"1","resourceId":"1","start":"2017-02-07T02:00:00","end":"2017-02-07T07:00:00","title":"event 1"},{"id":"2","resourceId":"2","start":"2017-02-07T05:00:00","end":"2017-02-07T22:00:00","title":"event 2"},{"id":"3","resourceId":"3","start":"2017-02-06","end":"2017-02-08","title":"event 3"},{"id":"4","resourceId":"4","start":"2017-02-07T03:00:00","end":"2017-02-07T08:00:00","title":"event 4"},{"id":"5","resourceId":"5","start":"2017-02-07T00:30:00","end":"2017-02-07T02:30:00","title":"event 5"}]}

No se molesten mucho en analizar el JSON, es irrelevante, solo lo puse como ejemplo, lo que sucede es que al poner la variable `$scope.datos` en el fragmento del codigo `resources : $scope.datos,` no me lee el JSON, por lo tanto, no me carga el resultado visual como deberia, pero si copio y pego la cadena en ese lugar, lo hace perfectamente. Estara fallando el `$scope` o que ocurre?

Answer (score 0):

Dices que al pegar la cadena tal cual si funciona. Y lo que estás recibiendo es un JSON. Has probado a usar `JSON.stringify()`

Algo así:

```
resourceLabelText: 'Salas disponibles',
        resources : JSON.stringfy($scope.datos),
```